# In MAC OS:- When I run ./gradew then. I am getting error could not find tools.jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPBpk.jpg)

Version:- java 8
Gradle:- 3.14

While in my system  I can open up to /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.Plugin only

I am not able to see /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.Plugin/Contents/Home

Can any help me why when I run ./gradlew the build fails at: compilejava and give error tools.jar not found

Note:- refer image for better view of error

Comment: tools.jar is a bit legacy. That message to me suggests an old version of gradle finding no JDK installed. Make sure you've got up-to-date gradle and JDK (as opposed to JRE)

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states - its  not a valid JDK install. The path `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.Plugin` is browser plugin for Java Applets.
You should install the JDK from Oracle / Open JDK / any other vendor. It will usually be installed in in `~/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` or `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`